# Copy all the groups from AD user to another

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In the company I work there are 2 domains. The first is the main domain and there is another sub-domain with trust relationship. 
I have tried to create a PowerShell script that when we create a new user, we can set a source username and copy all the groups he is a member of to a new user.

*For each user there are groups from both the main and the secondary domain*

I have created a script in PowerShell to copy the groups, but if the new user is in the sub-domain the only groups that will be added are the groups in the sub-domain, and if he is in the main domain, the groups he will be added to are in the main domain.

How can I make sure that all the groups will be added?

```
import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Collect the source and target users

$Source = Read-Host "Enter logon name of source user"
$Target = Read-Host "Enter logon name of target user"

# Set the domain for the user

$domain_Source=$null

$domainval = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter 1 for lpnet 2 for Sub-DB for the Source 
username'

if ($domainval -eq 1)
{
$domain_Source = "main.lpnet.com"
}
if ($domainval -eq 2)
{
$domain_Source = "sub-db.lpnet.com"
}



Get-ADUser -Identity $Source -Server $domain_Source -Properties memberof |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof|
Add-ADGroupMember -Members $Target -PassThru | 
Select-Object -Property SamAccountName
```

Comment: This is a lot easier with:
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

Comment: You will likely need to specify the [Credential](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617210.aspx) param with `Add-ADGroupMember` (and Get-ADUser) with an account that has the required permissions for the domain you're choosing.

Comment: I have tried to use the Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership commends, but it failed when I wanted to copy from a user that is found in the subdomain, and the new user is in the subdomain as well.